# Inequality with chromatic number and degrees of vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Let $(d_1,d_2, \ldots , d_n)$ be a sequence of vertices degrees in graph $G$. Prove that $\chi(G) \le \max_{i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n \}} \min \{d_i + 1, i \}$.

Comment: Any thoughts? (Try being greedy)

Comment: I take any vertex from the graph. If I color it to a certain color, then any other vertex that is connected to it must be colored in a different color. From here I can conclude that $\chi (G) \ge d_i + 1$ for every $i$. But I have to find upper limit...

Comment: No, your argument cannot prove the $\chi(G)\geq d_i+1$ for every $i$. It is not true. E.g., the square is $2$-colourable, but every $d_i=2$. By the greedy algorithm, it is trivial to verify that $\chi(G)\leq \max(d_i+1)$. Your problem is based on a similar idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every min produces a result out of two possibilities: either the value $i$ or the value $d_i+1$ is obtained (if the two coincides, we consider it as if $i$ were chosen). 
Let $j$ be the last index where $i$ is produced as a result (rather than $d_i+1$). 
Then you can colour the first $j$ vertices with all different colours, and finish the rest greedily.